# How do I 'correct' this matplotlib plotting routine?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am righteously confused with the coding paradigms offered by matplotlib. I am using code like this below to plot some data:

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=fig_size)  # plt=pyplot defined above
axes1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
axes1.plot(temp, depth, 'k-')
axes1.set_ylim(-600,0)
axes1.set_ylabel(r'Depth $(m)$')
axes1.set_xlim(0,80)
axes1.set_xlabel(r'Temperature (\textcelsius)')
axes1.set_xticks(np.arange(0,100,20))
axes1.grid(True)
plt.savefig(savedir + 'plot.svg', transparent=True)
```

I'd rather use mpl's object-oriented style than the pylab convenience functions. So question is if I only want to plot one curve, non-interactively, am I using the right figure creation style? (lines 1 & 2). It seems like a lot of separate calls are needed to format the axis labels and so on.

Comment: if you want to use the object oriented style it looks ok: see http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/faq/usage_faq.html#coding-styles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing looks fine. (And I agree, it's much cleaner to only use `pyplot` for figure creation and use the OO API for everything else.)

If you'd prefer to make the figure and axes in one call, use [`plt.subplots`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots).

Also, I find it's a bit cleaner to use `fig.savefig` instead of `plt.savefig`. It won't matter in this case, but that way you avoid having to worry about which figure is "active" in the state-machine interface.

For one last thing, you could set the x and y limits with a single call to `axes1.axis(...)`. This is purely a matter of preference.  `set_xlim` and `set_ylim` are arguably a more readable way of doing it.

The "setters" and "getters" are annoying, but date from when python didn't have properties, if I recall correctly.  They've been kept as the main methods partly for backwards compatibility, and partly so that "matlab-isms" like [`plt.setp`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.setp) are easier to write.   In fact, if you wanted you could do

```
plt.setp(ax, xlabel='Xlabel', ylabel='Ylabel', xticks=range(0, 100, 20))
```

This avoids having to do three separate calls to set the xlabel, ylabel, and xticks.  However, I personally tend to avoid it. I find it's better to be slightly more verbose in most cases.  If you find it cleaner or more convenient, though, there's nothing wrong with using `setp`.

As an example of how I'd write it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

depth = np.linspace(-600, 0, 30)
temp = (4 * np.random.random(depth.size)).cumsum()

fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
ax.plot(temp, depth, 'k-')
ax.axis([0, 80, -600, 0])
ax.set_ylabel(r'Depth $(m)$')
ax.set_xlabel(r'Temperature $(^{\circ}C)$')
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 100, 20))
ax.grid(True)

fig.savefig('plot.svg', transparent=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: sorry can't edit my comment any more: I just wanted to mention tight_layout (http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/tight_layout_guide.html#plotting-guide-tight-layout) because I think its useful especially for multiple subplots and can save some lines.

Comment: @bmu - `tight_layout` has nothing to do with the xticks, though. It only adjusts the position of the subplots so that axis labels, tick labels, etc don't overlap. Actually, given the axis ranges the OP wants, the default tick locations are exactly the same as what they specified through `xticks`, so they could leave it out in this specific case.

Comment: You are right, my mistake. For adjusting the xticklabels (not the positions, but the labels) I use `fig.autofmt_xdate()` which also works for none date labels. If you than call `tight_layout` most plots have a good layout without any further 'work'. Just wanted to mention this, your answer is perfectly right from my point of view.

Comment: @bmu I also only have mpl version 1.0.1, and i think `tight_layout()` is for 1.1+. Thanks Joe for the suggestions and effort you've put into the answer!